# In ggplot, how do you log scale with positive as well as negative values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logarithm

I have data that have exponential behavior in positive and negative direction. How can I log-scale them in ggplot?

Example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(c(exp(runif(100,0,10)),-exp(runif(100,0,10)))))
ggplot(dat, aes(seq_along(x),x)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Not working

```
dat <- data.frame(x=sample(c(exp(runif(100,0,10)),-exp(runif(100,0,10)))))
ggplot(dat, aes(seq_along(x),x)) + 
    geom_point() +
scale_y_continuous(trans='log')
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The second answer here could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924705/plot-negative-values-in-logarithmic-scale-with-ggplot-2

Answer (score 2):

The log transformation is not defined for negative values, which is why it does not work. An alternative would be to use a pseudo-log transformation, which is defined for all real numbers:

```r
    dat <- data.frame(x=sample(c(exp(runif(100, 0, 10)), -exp(runif(100, 0, 10)))))
    ggplot(dat, aes(seq_along(x), x)) + 
      geom_point() +
      scale_y_continuous(trans='pseudo_log')
```

Do note that for values close to zero the pseudo-log transformation approaches a linear transformation instead of a log transformation. This means a value like `0.2` will be plotted close to `0.2`, instead of close to `log(0.2)`, which equals to about `-1.6`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the 'pseudo_log' option. For better labels and grid lines, add for instance `breaks = c(-1, -100, -10000, 1, 100, 10000), minor_breaks = NULL` inside the `scale_y_continuous` parantheses. (`breaks` define where you have labels and grid lines, `minor_breaks` defines where you have grid lines only.)