# scattershot with inverted Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, reverse, transformation, scatter-plot

I'd like to plot a scatterplot with the data below using `minimum.sptm` in X-axis and `p.value` on Y-axis.

The point is, I'd like the `-log(p.value)` but displaying the `p.value`.

```
structure(list(minimun.sptm = c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 
0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 
0.9, 0.95, 1), p.value = c(0.217137180894596, 8.69138632923479e-06, 
5.19743435092154e-13, 2.86015251354523e-14, 5.51211423760726e-30, 
1.06397214811093e-34, 3.15922010250516e-36, 1.54383374085175e-36, 
3.17487635201757e-36, 1.65512592209202e-36, 2.19511495850264e-36, 
1.39210307866501e-36, 1.55834678312407e-35, 7.23531845274866e-34, 
9.6298173273593e-34, 2.05019326670673e-34, 6.9030663073707e-32, 
1.33364294302178e-32, 1.26879586574242e-28, 9.22917969013045e-37, 
3.31136440476303e-06)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried:

```
tt %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x= minimun.sptm, 
      y = p.value
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45))
```

And, as expected, I got:
[image]

But I want the Y-axis inverted and I didn't find the right function.
I tried `scale_y_continuous(trans = "-log")` but it doesn't work.

I also tried:

```
tt %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x= minimun.sptm, 
      y = p.value
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log") +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45))
```

And I got the error:

> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.

Another try was:

```
tt %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x= minimun.sptm, 
      y = p.value
    )
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45))
```

Which also didn't work.

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe you need `scale_y_reverse()`?

Comment: @aosmith thanks bot it doesn't work, I tried, I'll include in the question

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053899/how-to-get-a-reversed-log10-scale-in-ggplot2 ?

Comment: @MartinGal thanks, I was expecting something more directly but worked well.

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes Actually I was also surprised that there was no direct solution, but this one is fine.