# How to set Boxplot Y axis limits in millions

Tags: r, boxplot

When I do a boxplot diagram with the R boxplotfunction, this function prints the y-axis automatically.

```
boxplot(x=DF$Baseline.Investment, xlab="Baseline.Investment",col=c('green'))
```

I want the y axis limits changed to millions. Could someone help with this question?
Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9voJ.jpg)

Comment: Add this to your box plot: `ylim = c(0, 10000000)`

Comment: y axis limits are printed this way : 0e+00, 2e+06, 4e+06 etc. I want it to read it in thousands or millions. I am trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897243/labelling-logarithmic-scale-display-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rlnorm(100, 12, 2)
boxplot(x/1e6, ylab="Amount in Millions")
```

[image: Boxplot]

If you want more control over the axis labels, create your own axis:

```
boxplot(x, yaxt="n", ylab="Amount in Millions")
axis(2, c(0, 5e6, 1e7, 1.5e7), c("0", "5", "10", "15"), las=1)
```