# How to annotate() ggplot with latex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add latex text to a ggplot2 plot using `annotate()`. Using `expression()`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots) for adding latex to axis labels, does not seem to work.  To wit:

```
# Use expression() to create subscripted text
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(expression(text[subscript])) 

# But expression() in annotate adds nothing to the plot
p + annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label=expression(text[subscript])) 

# Passing regular text to annotate works fine
p + annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label="foo")
```

Why are `expression`s treated differently by `annotate` than by other ggplot functions? And how can I annotate with latex?

Comment: you might take a look at the `tikzDevice` package ...

Comment: Seems to be no longer actively maintained. (But still potentially useful!)

Comment: My understanding is that it's still pretty widely used, and functional, but in a current state of orphanage due to stricter CRAN/R CMD check rules ... it was last modified on R-forge 15 July 2012 ...

Comment: PS: current development status at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tikzdevice/73Hd2Eln3Qk

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the `parse` argument, without `expression`:

```
p + annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label="text[subscript]", parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you confirm for me whether you get any unusual behavior if you try using `label=expression(text[subscript]), parse = TRUE)`? (I haven't upgraded to 0.9.2 yet...)

Comment: Ok...still a little groggy this morning, and I did that by mistake first time through. Never seen that sort of response from R before. Weird.

Comment: First time I've seen that as well. It lets you correct the label argument with whatever you type after the '?'.

Comment: @Joran's comment - I saw ?, and then R Studio crashed (Max OSX 10.7.4, R 2.14.1, RStudio 0.96.330, ggplot2 0.9.1).

Comment: the option `parse = TRUE` makes it interpreted as `plotmath` annotation-like mathematical expression

Answer (score 72):

There is an `R` package called `latex2exp` which may be helpful. It has function `TeX` which accepts some LaTeX expressions enclosed with dollar sign `$` as in this example:

```
library(latex2exp)
library(ggplot2)

qplot(1, "A")+
     ylab(TeX("Formula: $\\frac{2hc^2}{\\lambda^\\beta}$"))+
     xlab(TeX("$\\alpha$"))
```

[image: Example]

More examples can be found in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html).

Comment: Your example works for labels, but the question was about annotate. Your example isn't working in an annotate layer for me, but, if you specify output='character' and add 'parse=TRUE' to the annotate call it does.  
  
  

`annotate(geom='text', x=3, y=3, label=Tex("$\\hat{Y} = B_0 + B_1X_1", output='character'), parse=TRUE)`

Comment: Hi do you know how to add italic style on the text?

Comment: @Jiaxiang are you familiar with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732949/italic-greek-letters-in-r-plot)

Comment: @Vilmantas Gegzna Yes, I read it before. What I want is to make the `Tex()` output in the italic style. I try `Tex(italic('...'))`, but it fails.

Comment: I skimmed through the [latex2exp vignette](ftp://cran.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) but did not notice anything about italic style. You may try looking look through more carefully. I'm not sure if **latex2exp** support italic style.

Answer (score 17):

The [tikzDevice](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/) package is back on CRAN (latest version 0.9 published Nov 2015).

Using `tikz` does require a full LaTeX installation; it may be easiest to do via `knitr` within a LaTeX document (just set `dev="tikz"` in the chunk options).  However, you can use it to create a standalone figure as well. Ironically, the hardest part of this question was getting a text subscript, which requires an additional LaTeX package (`fixltx2e`) for the `\textsubscript` command ...

```
library(tikzDevice)
## add a package to the defaults
options(tikzLatexPackages=
            c(getOption("tikzLatexPackages"),"\\usepackage{fixltx2e}"))
tikz("tikz.tex",standAlone=TRUE)
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(name="text\\textsubscript{subscript}")
p + annotate("text", x=10, y=40, label="text\\textsubscript{subscript}")
dev.off()

system("pdflatex tikz.tex")
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Takes a little while to compile, producing a bunch of warnings like ``Measuring dimensions of: \char77``, but it's my preferred solution when unicode lets me down (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690729/greek-letters-symbols-and-line-breaks-inside-a-ggplot-legend-label)

Comment: This is an awesome answer @BenBolker, I managed to adapt it to my own graph, but I am still struggling with adjusting the size (height and length) of the printed pdf file, any advice?

Comment: not offhand.  There should be something in the `tikz` options to let you deal with this, I would think?  If you can't figure it out I would say that posting a new question would be very sensible

Comment: As you pointed out, the solution is to use `width` and `height` options inside the `tikz()` function. For example,  in you answer it should be something like the following `tikz("tikz.tex",standAlone=TRUE, height=1,  width=1.5 )`. Thank you a lot @BenBolker, you saved the day (as always!).