# Italic greek letters in R plot?

Tags: r

Is it possible to italicize greek letters in R plots? Ideally the following code would result in italic greek letters:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, type="n")
text(8,4, expression(italic(gamma)~":"~italic(sigma))) #doesn't work...
text(2,2,expression(italic("this")~":"~italic("that")))
```

The plotmath documentation very clearly says that italic() won't work for greek letters, however, they do say that UTF-8 with \uxxxxx or \Uxxxxxxxx can be used to create italic greek symbols, however I have been unable to get this to work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this with utf or some other way?

There may be some Tex solutions, but I have not had success in getting the basic Tex examples to work on my system. I am open to them, but I may ask some follow-up questions.

The below code almost plots what I want, but not quite.

```
windows(family='serif') #name for Times in default windows gr device lib
plot(1:10, 1:10, type="n")
text(5,9, expression(italic(β)~":"~italic(α))) #1
text(5,7, paste("\u03B2",":","\u03B1",sep=" "), font=3) #2
text(5,5, expression(italic(beta)~":"~italic(alpha))) #3
text(5,3, expression(italic("\u03B2")~":"~italic("\u03B1"))) #4
text(5,1.5, expression(italic("\u03B2")~plain(":")~italic("\u03B1"))) #5
```

[image]

I need italic symbols and a non-italic ":".  In the top one (#1), the italic symbols look odd.  In the second one the italic symbols look right but the ":" is italic. Yes, the journal editor has caught that.

OS: windows 7 x64

Comment: so are you saying that `tikzDevice`-based solutions are *not* acceptable answers for this question ... ?

Comment: This sounds like the default "Greek" font is the old Symbol. Theoretically, the suggestion to use a properly encoded Unicode font ought to work; first thing then, of course, is to make sure the font *contains* Greek symbols.

Comment: Like `?plotmath` said, you can't have italic greek letters in a math expression. But if you use UTF character, you would make them italic the way you would any other plain text: `text(5,5, "\u03B2", font=3)`. Or a more complete example: `text(5,5, expression(beta~ ":" ~ "\u03B2" ~ italic(beta) ~ ":" ~ italic("\u03B2")))`

Comment: @BenBolker, edited post, I am open to it if you have an example, but I may ask follow-up questions...

Comment: @MrFlick, Ok, now that I am comparing them I am thinking the journal is not going to accept a non-math expression beta... looks like I need to make Tex work...somehow...

Comment: The Cairo package might be worth a try; `expression(italic(β))` worked on my machine. Then again, it has a tendency to write everything in italics.

Comment: the top 'beta' doesn't look like a real beta, it looks like a German "scharfe s" ß http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F

Comment: `text(5,3, expression(italic("\u03B2")~plain(":")~italic("\u03B1")) )` seems acceptable. These things are often OS specific and you have offered no information on this concern.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this one. Ended up making a data structure for future use and doing some searching on the "right way" to make Unicode characters (having failed with in various ways with `paste0("\u", n)` and what I thought would be clever workarounds.

```
greeks <- 
structure(list(grsym = c("α", "β", "γ", "δ", "ε", "ζ", 
"η", "θ", "ι", "κ", "λ", "μ", "ν", "ξ", "ο", "π", "ρ", 
"ς", "σ", "τ", "υ", "φ", "χ", "ψ", "ω", "Α", "Β", "Γ", 
"Δ", "Ε", "Ζ", "Η", "Θ", "Ι", "Κ", "Λ", "Μ", "Ν", "Ξ", 
"Ο", "Π", "Ρ", "Σ", "Τ", "Υ", "Φ", "Χ", "Ψ", "Ω"), 
    decUTF = c(945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 
    955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 
    967, 968, 969, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 
    922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 931, 932, 933, 934, 
    935, 936, 937), hexUTF = structure(c(945L, 946L, 947L, 948L, 
    949L, 950L, 951L, 952L, 953L, 954L, 955L, 956L, 957L, 958L, 
    959L, 960L, 961L, 962L, 963L, 964L, 965L, 966L, 967L, 968L, 
    969L, 913L, 914L, 915L, 916L, 917L, 918L, 919L, 920L, 921L, 
    922L, 923L, 924L, 925L, 926L, 927L, 928L, 929L, 931L, 932L, 
    933L, 934L, 935L, 936L, 937L), class = "hexmode"), htmlSym = c("&alpha;", 
    "&beta;", "&gamma;", "&delta;", "&epsilon;", "&zeta;", "&eta;", 
    "&theta;", "&iota;", "&kappa;", "&lambda;", "&mu;", "&nu;", 
    "&xi;", "&omicron;", "&pi;", "&rho;", "&sigmaf;", "&sigma;", 
    "&tau;", "&upsilon;", "&phi;", "&chi;", "&psi;", "&omega;", 
    "&Alpha;", "&Beta;", "&Gamma;", "&Delta;", "&Epsilon;", "&Zeta;", 
    "&Eta;", "&Theta;", "&Iota;", "&Kappa;", "&Lambda;", "&Mu;", 
    "&Nu;", "&Xi;", "&Omicron;", "&Pi;", "&Rho;", "&Sigma;", 
    "&Tau;", "&Upsilon;", "&Phi;", "&Chi;", "&Psi;", "&Omega;"
    ), Description = c("GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER GAMMA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER DELTA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER ZETA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER ETA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER THETA", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER KAPPA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER LAMBDA", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER MU", "GREEK SMALL LETTER NU", "GREEK SMALL LETTER XI", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER OMICRON", "GREEK SMALL LETTER PI", "GREEK SMALL LETTER RHO", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER FINAL SIGMA", "GREEK SMALL LETTER SIGMA", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU", "GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON", "GREEK SMALL LETTER PHI", 
    "GREEK SMALL LETTER CHI", "GREEK SMALL LETTER PSI", "GREEK SMALL LETTER OMEGA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ALPHA", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER BETA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER GAMMA", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER DELTA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER EPSILON", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ZETA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ETA", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER THETA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER IOTA", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER KAPPA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER LAMBDA", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER MU", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER NU", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER XI", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMICRON", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PI", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER RHO", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER TAU", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER UPSILON", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PHI", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER CHI", "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER PSI", 
    "GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA")), .Names = c("grsym", "decUTF", 
"hexUTF", "htmlSym", "Description"), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = "data.frame")
```

So that's the data. The `intToUtf8` function is the answer, and I implemented it within a `bquote` strategy:

```
start_e <- expression()   # Define the class of the expression vector.
plot(5,5)
text(2+(1:5),4, sapply( greeks[1:5,3],
                        function(x) c(start_e, bquote(italic(.(intToUtf8(x)))) ) ) )
```

This is on a Mac, so it's possible this is not a general solution. This is what I see on my device:

```
png(width=480, height=200); plot(1:10, 1:10, type="n")
text(5,6, expression(italic(β)~":"~italic(α))) 
text(5,3, expression(italic("\u03B2")~plain(":")~italic("\u03B1")) );dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Heh. I just copied a screen scrape from a webpage, ran it through `read.fwf` and cleaned it up to the best of my limited ability.

Comment: I notified the owners of that website about the misspelings of "lambda".

Comment: Might not be general.  I tried it on windows and it plots the letters in a different sense of "italic." I have supplied some code illustrating the contrast in the original post.

Comment: Evidently I need to find a Mac for this figure.

Comment: There are probably cheaper strategies. What fonts are in your device defaults? ...and did you try `expression(italic("\u03B2")~":"~italic("\u03B1"))`

Comment: TT fonts, Times New Roman, Courier New, Arial. Courier New appears to be the default. Times NR is the font I am supposed to use, see edited post.

Answer (score 0):

**If** it's convenient to have (La)TeX rendering in your output pipeline, I would strongly recommend using the `tikzDevice` package to get arbitrary (La)TeX typesetting in your figures.

**Advantages**

- typefaces etc. etc. can easily be made consistent between your text and figures
- access to *all* LaTeX typesetting machinery

**Disadvantages**

- if you don't already have a TeX system installed, it can be a huge pain
- if you don't already know TeX and want to do complicated equations, you have to learn a new system

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("plot.tex",standAlone=TRUE)
plot(1:4, 1:4, type="n")
text(1,3, "$\\gamma:\\sigma$") #doesn't work...
text(2,2,"\\textit{this}:\\textit{that}")
dev.off()
```

### convert TeX -> PDF -> PNG

```
system("pdflatex plot.tex")
system("convert plot.pdf plot.png")
```

[image]