# Italic Greek Psi in expression in y label of plot

Tags: r, plot, expression, symbols

I am attempting to use an italic capital Psi in the y label of a `plot`.  So far I have been able to use:

1. a non-italic Greek Psi
2. an italic word
3. an italic Greek Beta

However, I have not been able to use an italic Greek Psi.  Perhaps I am not using the correct code for Psi?  Perhaps the default font does not include a Psi but does include a Beta?

Here are examples I have come up with so far:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x^1.5

# Greek symbol works
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - psi[13])),
xlab = 'my x label')

# italic word works
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression(italic('Daily ') ~(1 - psi[13])),
xlab = 'my x label')

# italic Greek Beta symbol works
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732949/italic-greek-letters-in-r-plot
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - italic('\u03B2'[13]))),
xlab = 'my x label')

# italic Greek Psi symbol does not work
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - italic('\u03A8'[13]))),
xlab = 'my x label')
```

If `'\u03A8'` is not the correct code for Psi can you tell me what the correct code is and where I can find it?  I have tried other fonts without success, as shown here:

```
windows(family='serif')
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - italic('\u03A8'[13]))),
xlab = 'my x label')

windows(family='sans')
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - italic('\u03A8'[13]))),
xlab = 'my x label')

windows(family='symbol')
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - italic('\u03A8'[13]))),
xlab = 'my x label')
```

I checked in `MSWord` and the symbol there I think is `03C8`, not `03A8`.  However, `'\u03C8'` does not work either in `R`.

I also tried using the approach described in an answer here:

[Italic greek letters in R plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732949/italic-greek-letters-in-r-plot)

That answer seems to require loading a somewhat large data set called `greeks`.  If I do that and then use these lines:

```
start_e <- expression()
sapply( greeks[48,3], function(x) c(start_e, bquote(italic(.(intToUtf8(x))[13]) ) ) )
```

This is returned:

```
expression(italic("Ψ"[13]))
```

However, if I use:

```
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black', 
ylab = sapply( greeks[48,3], function(x) c(start_e, bquote(italic(.(intToUtf8(x))) ) ) ),
xlab = 'my x label')
```

The y-label is the string: *`<U+03A8>`*

Comment: Well I think you ave the right code as `italic('\u03A8'[13])` render okay in ubuntu14.04. Also , `\u03C8` renders okay (it is small letter psi)

Comment: \u03A8 is correct code, but only some the most popular greek letters are supported in general.
It is case of your encoding - check if `Sys.getlocale()` return some UTF-8 encoding.
If it is not, use some, ie `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_EN.UTF-8")`


You can also try to save it as pdf to make sure if you support extra greeks letters.
`pdf('some.pdf')
plot(y, x, type = 'l', col = 'black',
     ylab = expression('Daily ' ~(1 - italic('\u03A8'[13]))),
     xlab = 'my x label')
text(10,6,'\u03A8')
dev.off()`
Here you can see Psi above the curve in your plot in R, but not in pdf.

Comment: @Abderyt Thank you.  Unfortunately, when I try to set the locale I get this message: `[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_EN.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_EN.UTF-8" cannot be honored`

Comment: If you are linux user it is simle:
check your locales: `locale -a` and add if it is missing by `sudo locale-gen enEN.UTF-8`, then update `sudo update-locale`. Now you can use en_EN.UTF-8. 

If you are windows user google how to change locale.
There is something in (can differ with respect to system version)
Control Panel -> Language and Region -> Administrative -> Change system locale button
but it can only change language for non unicode characters (for your example you shoud use italian)