# How to plot beta in italics in R?

Tags: r, plot, unicode

I am looking for a way to plot a 'mathematical italic small beta' in R. Somehow, the unicode for that symbol ('\U1D6FD') doesn't work. I am not interested in just typing in the letter β (as in topright), because it is not the symbol I want.

```
plot(1,col="white")
legend("topleft", legend=paste("\U03B2","\U1D5D","\U1D66","  \U1D6FD"),cex=2,bty="n")
legend("topright", legend=substitute(italic("β")), cex=2,bty="n")
legend("bottomleft", legend=substitute(italic(beta)), cex=2,bty="n")
```

I found here [Italic greek letters in R plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732949/italic-greek-letters-in-r-plot) that it is possible by changing the font to serif:

```
par(family = 'serif') 
legend("bottomright",expression(italic("\u03B2")), cex=2,bty="n")
```

However, (1) I don't want to have the beta in serif and (2) in the end, I want to combine the beta with other text in my x-axis, and that text should not be in serif nor in italics but (as standard) in sans. I do not know of a way to combine sans and serif in one line/axis label.

Help would be much appreciated!

see my attempts here：[image]

Comment: Your `topleft` example works just fine on my system. I see the symbol you want. Please provide some infos about your system setup (OS, R version, locale, fonts, ...).

Comment: I use Windows 7, 64 bit. R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30). locale (found via `sessionInfo()`): English_United States.1252. Font is the standard (sans), which I made sure of through: `par(family = 'sans')`.

Comment: `windowsFonts()$sans` returns `"TT Arial"` on my system. `par()$family` is an empty string.

Comment: The same for me (it doesn't matter if I set `par()$family` to give an empty string or not). It must be something else with my system setup..

Comment: I don't think it matters but I use R 3.5.1 and Windows 10. I don't have any ideas.