# Italicise greek letters in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is getting very fussy now, but is there any way to italicise facet headings in ggplot2?

I have no problems getting the greek characters

```
i2 <- iris %>% transform(Species = factor(ifelse(Species == "setosa", "mu",
                                                 ifelse(Species == "versicolor", "sigma", "tau"))))


ggplot(i2, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       facet_grid(.~Species, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]

However if I try to italicise

```
i3 <- iris %>% transform(Species = factor(ifelse(Species == "setosa", "italic(mu)",
                                                 ifelse(Species == "versicolor", "bold(sigma)", "tau"))))

ggplot(i3, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       facet_grid(.~Species, labeller = label_parsed)
```

Nothing happens and it looks the same as the original plot.

Comment: plotmath doesn't natively handle italic Greek: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732949/italic-greek-letters-in-r-plot . If it's OK for your workflow to include LaTeX, I'd recommend TikZ output.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Bolker, I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending on @Ben Bolker comment, you can work this out using Unicode characters for the Greek letters you want to italize / make bold. This will also work in case where you might want to to this by means of `italic()` or `bold()` functions within `expression()` calls.

In your case it is enough to replace `mu` with `\u03BC`, and `sigma` with `\u03C3`:

```
i3 <- iris %>% transform(Species = factor(ifelse(Species == "setosa", "italic(\u03BC)",
                                                 ifelse(Species == "versicolor", "bold(\u03C3)", "tau"))))

ggplot(i3, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(.~Species, labeller = label_parsed)
```