# How to place +/- plus minus operator in text annotation of plot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, text, plot, ggplot2, latex

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work for me:

```
a <- ggplot()
a <- a + geom_point(aes(x=seq(0,1,0.1), y=seq(0,1,0.1)))
a <- a + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.3, label="myplot")
a <- a + annotate("text", x=0.5,y=0.2,label=expression(%+-%))
```

I have also tried the following as pointed out by [How to annotate() ggplot with latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514612/how-to-annotate-ggplot-with-latex) with no luck:

```
a <- a + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.1, label="%+-%", parse=TRUE)
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
a <- a + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.1, label="\pm", parse=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is possible to use the unicode representation (`\u00B1`):

```
a <- ggplot()
a <- a + geom_point(aes(x=seq(0,1,0.1), y=seq(0,1,0.1)))
a <- a + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.3, label="myplot")
a + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.2, label="\u00B1")
```

Or you can use the `±` symbol directly, by copying and pasting it from somewhere.

```
a + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.2, label="±")
```

Answer (score 12):

This works:

```
a0 <- ggplot()
a0 <- a0 + geom_point(aes(x=seq(0,1,0.1), y=seq(0,1,0.1)))
a0 + annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.1, label="'' %+-% '' ", parse=TRUE)
```

The key idea is that `%+-%` is an *operator*, so it has to operate on something, i.e. it has to be in the form `x %+-% y`; in this case I've made `x` and `y` be blank strings.

You could also use `phantom()`:

```r
annotate("text", x=0.5, y=0.1, label = "phantom() %+-% phantom()", parse = TRUE)
```

If you want to use full LaTeX-style markup like `\pm` you need to go down the rabbit hole of [tikzDevice](http://iltabiai.github.io/tips/latex/2015/09/15/latex-tikzdevice-r.html).  However, `latex2exp::TeX` can often provide a useful hint, e.g.:

```r
latex2exp::TeX("\\pm")
##    LaTeX: \pm 
## plotmath: phantom() %+-% phantom()
```

Comment: phantom also works, although it is almost completely undocumented

Comment: Reading and re-reading the plotmath page is necessary. And actually it is `phantom()` that is needed.