# Can I create an empty ggplot2 plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots) demonstrates how to put an equation into a ggplot2 qplot.

```
q <- qplot(cty, hwy, data = mpg, colour = displ)
q + xlab(expression(beta +frac(miles, gallon)))
```

How could I create an empty ggplot2 plot so that I could add the label to an empty canvas?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame()
ggplot(df) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100)
```

and based on @ilya's recommendation, `geom_blank` is perfect for when you already have data and can just set the scales based on that rather than define it explicitly.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_blank()
```

Comment: Yeah, that works and I guess that answers my question. I suppose the question I should have asked was how to create a plot that that consists only of a label.

Answer (score 54):

```
ggplot() + theme_void()
```

No need to define a dataframe.

Answer (score 17):

Since none of the answers explicitly state how to make a plot that consists only of a label, I thought I'd post that, building off the existing answers.

### In `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot() +
    theme_void() +
    geom_text(aes(0,0,label='N/A')) +
    xlab(NULL) #optional, but safer in case another theme is applied later
```

Makes this plot:

[image]

The label will always appear in the center as the plot window resizes.

### In `cowplot`:

```
cowplot::ggdraw() +
    cowplot::draw_label('N/A')
```

`ggdraw()` makes a blank plot while `draw_label` draws a label in the middle of it:

[image]