# Labeling Y-axis in R

Tags: r

Suppose I need to plot a sequence of x and y as:

```
x <- seq(0, 10, by =0.001)
gx1 <- exp(-(x^2))
plot(x, gx1, type="l", lty=1, lwd=3,
xlab="x", ylab="G_b(x)",ylim=c(0,1))
```

But I want to add $\bar{f}_k(x)$ as a label on the Y-axis. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: check out plotmath http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
plot(x, gx1, type="l", lty=1, lwd=3, xlab="x", 
ylab=expression(bar(f)[b](x)),ylim=c(0,1))
```

I found the solution at

[Getting LaTeX into R Plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots)

by Christopher DuBois

Comment: Thank you csta. But how come the 'bar' on f is not showing up?

Comment: Not sure, They are showing up for me.  I'm using R 2.15.1, on a Mac where the R install came from brew.  If you type ?plotmath into the R command line do you get a help page? Edit: I believe it is there but maybe it is off screen. Do you see the bar with expression(bar(f))?