# R: print text with subscripts

Tags: r

I know I can print to console strings that have unicode symbols in them by escaping them, however, I was wondering if there is a way of using `expression` and `paste` like in a plot's title (essentially displaying mathematical expressions using {plotmath}, but to save it in a vector of characters, so that when I display the said vector in console, it looks like LaTeX.
Any advice? Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I am still learning, if the question does not make any sense in R, please don't be too harsh.

Comment: I cannot understand what is requested. Please post example input and output.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots ?

Comment: @seaotternerd That post is discussing the common problem of displaying LaTeX-like text in plot's titles and axis labels. This is easily solved with {plotmath} by doing some fancy footwork with `expression`, `paste` and `substitute`. My problem is trying to replicate the same kind of behaviour in an ordinary string (that I can then display on a console), instead of a plot.

@BondedDust It is kind of difficult to post an example short of making a picture. What I basically want, is to have the same level of text sophistication (LaTeX) that I normally have in a label on a plot, on console display.

Comment: Looks like it should be possible if you have a unicode compliant console. I don't know of a neat pre-existing way to do it from R (although one may well exist), but this might be a good starting point: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96591/is-it-possible-to-show-mathematical-symbols-in-the-terminal