# Likelihood character in plot label

Tags: r, plot

How can I have the likelihood character (the curvy L https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function ) appear in a plot axis in base R?

Comment: Whats about a simple `L` in italics using `plot(1:10, xlab = expression(italic("L")))`?

Comment: You might have look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots).

Comment: `"\U2112"` should do it but I only get a square (while I do get a small script l with `"\U2113"`...)