# How to add Latex code in ggplot2 legend labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex

Consider the following example:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),B=c(4,1,2,1,3,2,4,1),C=c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(x = A, y = B,color = C))
```

I would like to change the labels in the legend from "A" and "B" to Latex formulae, say "$A^h_{t-k}$" and "$B^h_{t-k}$", respectively.

Apparently, according to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots), ways to achieve this exist. However, I am really struggling to get it to work. Could somebody break it down for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 B = c(4,1,2,1,3,2,4,1),
                 C = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")
                 )
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = A, y = B,color = C)) +
    scale_color_discrete(labels = c(expression(A[t-k]^h), expression(B[t-k]^h)))
```

[image]

Comment: This did not work for axis titles for me. Is there a way to accomplish that? So `scale_x_continuous(expression(\Delta))`, for example?

Comment: `scale_x_continuous(expression(Delta))` does work for me

Comment: Ah, excellent. I will give this a try. Now that I see the reply, apologies on not directly just checking the package. It probably states that something like `\` is not required and I just didn't understand. Thanks for the prompt correction!

Answer (score 21):

To use real LaTeX syntax, you can use the `latex2exp` package. Note the use of `unname()`, this is necessary.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
df <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
                 B = c(4,1,2,1,3,2,4,1),
                 C = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")
)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = A, y = B,color = C)) +
  scale_color_discrete(labels = unname(TeX(c("$A_{t-k}^h$", "$B_{t-k}^h$"))))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-29 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: This worked great, though slight caveat for `\foo` calls. I had to use `TeX("$\\Delta")` in my code. Just a heads up that double `\\` escapes may be necessary.

Comment: "Note the use of unname(), this is necessary." Why

Comment: (Perhaps already-inferred after all this time...) Likely because when `labels=` is given a _named_ vector of values, it tries to associate the names in the `values=` argument with actual values in the data aesthetic. For example, using RoryNolan's code, if we instead use `names(.)`, we see that `TeX` returns a named vector with names `c("$A_{t-k}^h$", "$B_{t-k}^h$")`. Those names do not appear in the raw data, so they will not be applied to the data values `"A"` and `"B"` appropriately. One could replace `unname(.)` with `setNames(., c("B","A"))` instead for a similar (though reversed) result.