# How to rename the labels of the fill variable in a grouped plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need change the labels with custom labels that are not in the data because I want to introduce some latex formulas in the labels.

To illustrate the issue I will use an example I copied from https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.

```r
# library
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
 
# Grouped
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

This example produces the following plot:

[image]

Instead of the labels `Nitrogen`, `normal`, and `stress`, I want to use latex formulas as `TeX('$\\alpha^2$')`, `TeX('$\\beta^3$')` and `TeX('$\\alpha+\\beta$')`.  Of course, I prefer to modify the plot, but not the data.  How can I do it?

Comment: Did you try any of these solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310088/how-to-add-latex-code-in-ggplot2-legend-labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `expression()` where you can wrap all your labels and then use `scale_fill_manual()` or `scale_fill_discrete()`:

```
# library
library(ggplot2)
# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)
#Labs
labs <- expression(alpha^2,beta^3,alpha+beta)
# Grouped
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(labels=labs,values=c('tomato','cyan3','palegreen'))
```

Output:

[image]

Or this option for elegant spacing:

```
#Labs
labs <- expression(alpha^2,beta^3,~~~alpha+beta)
# Grouped
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(labels=labs,values=c('tomato','cyan3','palegreen'))
```

Output:

[image]

Using `scale_fill_discrete()`:

```
# Grouped
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_discrete(labels=labs)
```

Output:

[image]